# List comprehension in nested ifs

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am a newbie trying to understand list comprehensions in python. My question is different from another posts.

I was asked to write list comprehension code to get the following output:

All odd numbers from 1 to 30 (both inclusive). Those that are multiples of 5 will be marked with an 'x'.

> [1, 3, '5x', 7, 9, 11, 13, '15x', 17, 19, 21, 23, '25x', 27, 29]

For this, I tried to get it with normal for and if ways. This is my solution and it worked:

```
odds = []

for i in list(range(1,30+1)):
  if i%2 !=0:
    odds.append(i)
    if i%5 == 0:
      odds.append(f'{i}x')
      odds.remove(i)

print(odds)
```

In the image you can find my failed list comprehension attempt. I need some light to place the rest of the stuff correctly.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You cannot solve this problem in one line using list comprehension alone. You need the ternary operator (enclosed in the parentheses).

```
[(n if n%5 else f'{n}x') for n in range(1,31) if n%2]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about the order of the items, you can avoid needing the ternary operator ([conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)) by concatenating the lists resulting from two list comprehensions, e.g.

```
[n for n in range(1,31,2) if n%5 != 0] + [f'{n}x' for n in range(1,31,2) if n%5 == 0]
```

... which produces:

> [1, 3, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, 19, 21, 23, 27, 29, '5x', '15x', '25x']

Alternatively, at the risk of making this look like code golf:

```
[[f'{n}x',n][min(n%5,1)] for n in range(1,31,2)]
```

... produces:

> [1, 3, '5x', 7, 9, 11, 13, '15x', 17, 19, 21, 23, '25x', 27, 29]

I've used the expression `min(n%5,1)` to index the list `[f'{n}x',n]` and thus select either item 0 or item 1 in the list, depending on whether `n` is divisible by 5 or not -- also without using the [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

Comment: @Oskr if they're both the same, it only has one choice it could make.  And that choice is the correct one!

Answer (score 2):

Alternate workaround:

```
numlist = [(i,f'{i}x')[not i%5] for i in range(31) if i%2]
print(numlist)
# [1, 3, '5x', 7, 9, 11, 13, '15x', 17, 19, 21, 23, '25x', 27, 29]
```

Comment: I think this answer wins the [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) prize for this question!